# How to fetch specific number of row on basis of score

Tags: mysql

Have to show on specific count . Means i have to show max score value 4 times then less than that score to 3 times and so on

I have table like:-

```
ID              Score

 1               1
 2               1
 3               1
 4               1
 5               2
 6               2
 7               2
 8               3
 9               3
10               4
11               4
12               4
```

and I am expecting output like:-

```
   Score
    1
    1
    1
    2
    2
    3
    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Score
FROM
(SELECT a.Score, a.ID, count(*) as RN FROM TableName a
JOIN TableName b ON a.Score = b.Score AND a.ID >= b.ID
GROUP BY a.Score, a.ID) T
WHERE RN>1
```

Result:

```
SCORE
1
1
1
2
2
3
4
4
```

An example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69d61/13).

**Explanation:**

In the inner query, we are selecting a row number partitioned by ID and order by score. And then we select Score from the inner query whose Row number is greater than 1 (inorder to omit 1 record).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.marks = x.marks 
   AND y.id <= x.id 
  GROUP 
     BY x.marks
      , x.id 
 HAVING COUNT(0) <= MAX(4-x.marks)
  ORDER 
     BY marks DESC,id;